# How would you label someone that generates ruses?

Tags: meaning

Someone who constantly tells lies can be labeled as a liar.

Is there a word that describes someone as a person that constantly uses ruses(sp?)?

I found that [in the definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ruse), if you go to the old english get the following: 1375-1425; late Middle English (noun use of obsolete rusen to detour) < Middle French, derivative of ruser to retreat.

So a liar is someone who lies, a cheater is someone who cheats, what do you call someone who uses the ruse as a common activity?

Also, if possible, I am looking for a word that utilizes the word "ruse." Forgive my attempt but something like a "ruser." (I know that isn't a word)

Comment: conman? con-artist? or maybe Prankster if it is less malicious?

Comment: I updated the question to better ask what I was hoping for. But those work.

Comment: Dictionaries usually list agent nouns under the headword. If there aren't any under 'ruse', there probably aren't any with that root.

Comment: Since the definition of _ruse_ is essentially _trick_, you might use _trickster_ in much the same way.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I hadn't even thought of that. I was also hoping there was a word I hadn't heard before that defined a "ruser" in this way, lol. Thank you all.

Comment: A *provocateur*?

Comment: *Russian* would probably not be the first best choice.:-)

Answer (score 1):

> **Trickster**
>
> In, *When Br'er Rabbit Meets Coyote*, the argument is posited that the Br'er Rabbit stories were derived from a mixture of African and Native American mythology, thus attributing part of the credit for the formation of the tales and wiles of Br'er Rabbit to "Indian captivity narratives" and the rabbit trickster found in Cherokee mythology.

[image]

> See, Wikipedia, “Trickster” [**Link**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trickster)
>
> **Rascal** *noun*:
>
> • a mischievous or cheeky person, especially a child or man
>
> see, Google.com [**Link**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=Rascal+d&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=rascal+definition&gs_l=hp..1.0l5.0.0.4.1227624...........0.ESl2SrYHHbM&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> **Fibber** *noun*:
>
> • a person who tells lies “research that shows that children learn to become *fibbers* at a remarkably early age.”
>
> *Synonyms* fabricator, fabulist, prevaricator, storyteller
>
> See, Merriam-Webster Thesaurus [**Link**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/fibber)
>
> **Mountebank** *noun*: plural noun: mountebanks
>
> • a person who deceives others, especially in order to trick them out of their money; a charlatan.
>
> *synonyms*: swindler, charlatan, confidence trickster, fraud, fraudster, impostor, trickster, hoaxer
>
> see, Google.com [**Link**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=mounteban&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=mountebank+definition&gs_l=hp..4.0l5.0.0.0.18093...........0.1l0P_T6KnDY&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> **Rogue** *noun*:; plural noun: rogues
>
> **1**. a dishonest or unprincipled man.
>
> See, Google.com [**Link**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=rogue+def&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=rogue+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.2.43930...........0.i27Dc7jWbQA&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is **schemer**. That is one who schemes, used in the general descriptive sense.